# What is the best way to save ssh public key in custom vagrant box?

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I often see unofficial documents that says you should save `vagrant` user’s ssh public key when creating your own box like below:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And when `vagrant up` with the box, the following message is shown:

```
default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
default: 
default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
```

It seems to me that mitchellh’s `vagrant.pub` key above is not appropriate.

What is the best way to save `vagrant` user’s ssh public key?

Comment: You have to build your own keys: see `ssh-keygen`'s man page!

Comment: The key at `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/` are insecure because everybody could download both: private and public key!!! **Don't use them!!!**

Comment: How do people do with this when publishing their own boxes at Vagrant Cloud? Do they build their own keys?

Comment: Yes! Use: `ssh-keygen -b <numbits>`, see `man ssh-keygen`!

Comment: You could also forward you key using `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and then add `config.ssh.forward_agent = true` to your Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key you point on raw.githubusercontent.com is a sample to no be used.

The returned message seem tell that another *keypair* is automatically generated:

> ```
> default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
> default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
> default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
> ```

so if everything is going correctly, your container now use a new *public key* in `/home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys` and your local host use a new *private key* in `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Compare this files with files you originally downloaded, look at modification time of both files (on local host and in vagrant container)

### Build your own key

Simply run:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/vagrant-dedicated
```

see `man ssh-keygen` for *key length*, *cipher*, etc...

Sample output:

- dialog:

  ```
  Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
  Enter same passphrase again:
  ```
- Simple output:

  ```
  Generating public/private rsa key pair.
  Your identification has been saved in vagrant-dedicated.
  Your public key has been saved in vagrant-dedicated.pub.
  The key fingerprint is:
  SHA256:U2YfVbMlCUed7tXrvf3xBQoLB3glpSpto4hwdjTKwV0 user @host  
  The key's randomart image is:
  +---[RSA 2048]----+
  |      E ..o .o==+|
  | . . . . +   o.o=|
  |  o + . + + . ...|
  | . + o o = . . .o|
  |. = o = S o . o o|
  |.+ o + . + o . + |
  |. . .     . . ..o|
  |               .*|
  |               .*|
  +----[SHA256]-----+
  ```

This will create two files:

```
ls -l ~/.ssh/vagrant-dedicated*
-rw------- 1 user  user  1679 Oct 20 12:18 vagrant-dedicated
-rw-r--r-- 1 user  user   394 Oct 20 12:18 vagrant-dedicated.pub


head -n1 ~/.ssh/vagrant-dedicated*
==> vagrant-dedicated <==
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

==> vagrant-dedicated.pub <==
ssh-rsa AAAAB3...0y/5 user@host
```

Replace content of containers `/home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys` by content of `~/.ssh/vagrant-dedicated.pub`, then use `vagrant-dedicated` as private key for ssh connection.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/vagrant-dedicated vagrant@container
```

#### Note about fingerprint

Before 1st connection to a new target host, `ssh` will prompt you about host's fingerprint.

You could compare output of

```
ssh-keygen -vlf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

on target vagrant container with output of your 1st connection output:

```
ssh -o VisualHostKey=true -i ~/.ssh/vagrant-dedicated vagrant@container
```

First run will begin output like:

```
The authenticity of host 'container (10.12.34.56)' can't be established.
```

Then, the ***fingerprint***, something like

```
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:9M+2wGn0nZO3GPYkWuuxzXqI3nIbk5IJJ5xwhsxwbXk
```

And the ***Ascii art*** representation:

```
+---[ECDSA 256]---+
|     . .. .      |
|      = .+ E     |
|       =oo.      |
|       .=..      |
|        S=o.     |
|         o+=o..o |
|          =+*X*..|
|         . =*+#+.|
|          .o=O+= |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

Both commands must give identical *fingerprint* and *ascii art*.